# How to efficiently find the best match between two tables

Tags: r, data.table

I have a

1. a table of yield curves that predicts the biological growth of a population over time under a wide variety of starting conditions; and
2. a table of measurements that provides an actual measurement of a particular population at a specific age.

I would like to identify the specific yield curve that best describes each individual measurement by matching the measured yield to the yield curve most similar to the measurement at that age. Due to the size of the yield curve database and the number of measurements, the process I have below is very slow. Is there any way to speed up this process? I have been trying a number of paths through data.table in R and SQL but not landing on anything that is very efficient. I feel like there would be an efficient data.table ish way to join the two tables but the mapply function I'm using is really slow when I try to scale it up.

```
library(data.table)
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(ggplot2)

# select all the yield curves
sql_query <- "SELECT yc_id, age, yield FROM yield"
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "../output/yield_curve.db")
yield_db <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)

# convert to data.table
yield_db <- as.data.table(yield_db)
yield_db[,yc_id := as.factor(yc_id)]

summary(yield_db[,.(age,yield)])
```

```
      age          yield       
 Min.   :  0   Min.   :   0.0  
 1st Qu.: 30   1st Qu.:  36.1  
 Median : 60   Median : 285.5  
 Mean   : 60   Mean   : 497.1  
 3rd Qu.: 90   3rd Qu.: 786.9  
 Max.   :120   Max.   :3486.3
```

Plot of some sample yields

```
# Sample some curves for plot
sample_count <- 500
sample_yc <- yield_db[,.(yc_id), by=.(yc_id)][sample(.N,sample_count)]$yc_id
ggplot(data = yield_db[yc_id %in% sample_yc], aes(x = age, y = yield, group=as.factor(yc_id))) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.1)
```

[image: sample yields]

```
sql_query <- "SELECT measure_id, measured_yield, measured_age 
FROM measurement"
measurement_db <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)

# convert to data.table
measurement_db <- as.data.table(measurement_db)

summary(measurement_db)

ggplot(data = measurement_db, aes(x = measured_age, y = measured_yield)) +
  geom_point(colour="orange")
```

```
   measure_id    measured_yield     measured_age   
 Min.   :  1.0   Min.   :   0.00   Min.   : 18.00  
 1st Qu.:108.8   1st Qu.:  80.68   1st Qu.: 35.00  
 Median :235.0   Median : 216.66   Median : 51.00  
 Mean   :226.7   Mean   : 299.58   Mean   : 53.76  
 3rd Qu.:342.2   3rd Qu.: 452.38   3rd Qu.: 67.00  
 Max.   :458.0   Max.   :1998.31   Max.   :119.00
```

[image: measurements]

Find a matching yield curve for each known measurement. This is the step that takes too long. Essentially looping through row of the measurements to find the closest matching yield curve. When I try to scale this up to >100,000 measurements, it takes far too long.

```
# Function to find the closest matching species
# using measured age (m_age) and measured yield (m_yield)
find_best_yc <- function(m_age, m_yield) {
  yc_id <- yield_db[age == m_age, .(yc_id, yield)][
    # pick the closest match by yield
    order(abs(yield-m_yield))][1,yc_id]
  return (yc_id)
}

measurement_db[, yield_curve:=mapply(FUN=find_best_yc, measured_age, measured_yield)]
```

Plot the matching yields

```
ggplot(data = yield_db[yc_id %in% measurement_db$yield_curve], 
                       aes(x = age, y = yield, group=as.factor(yc_id))) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I wonder if something like PCA could help here as a more efficient categorization method. Once you express each curve by its principal components, then new data could be mapped to that space to quickly identify the closest matches, and then you could pick the best numerically.

Comment: Use parameter estimation instead of bruteforcing. Comparing all data points of all empirical curves to all datapoints in the reference is overkill,  Estimate the Hill coefficient n  for all curves in for both sets, and compare those using RMSD.

Comment: Or any other sigmoid curve used in your field of biology

Comment: Your sample data seems to show two typical yield curves -- one type that monotonically grows, another type that declines between age 70-80. For much of the initial years, these two curves types largely overlap, though their slopes are distinct. Given only a single observation from that overlapping range, it seems two distinct ensuing path types are possible. So it might be more accurate to say there's X% chance that its on a growing path that looks like one thing, but also a Y% chance that it is shorter-lived and will instead look like something else.

Comment: @JonSpring you are correct, there are two main types of yields. I can identify if the measured yield follows the decline path based on other the presence of other measured attributes collected. I didn’t include in the find_best_yc function just for simplicity, but the full implementation would filter to only suitable yields based on these other measured attributes.